# What can I change data.addcolumn first parameter in google sheets in order for me to be able to type in string?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, numbers, google-visualization

I commented out which line to change, and I want to change the first parameter in order to be able to change the number to a string.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Months since start of COVID 19 (November 2019 = 0 and June 2020 = 8)');
      //change line below
      data.addColumn('number', 'Recovered');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Death');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Known Cases');

      data.addRows([
        [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
        [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
        [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
        [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
        [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
        [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
        [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
        [8,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6]
      ]);
```

Comment: not sure I follow, will you please clarify? you can simply change `'number'` to `'string'` -- but if you want to draw a chart, this will only work with a Table chart...

Comment: I want to label the axis based on dates (e.g. Jan 03), but I cant do that because the first parameter of data.addColumn is `'number'`

Comment: Maybe you would want the type to be `'date'` instead of `'number'`? What's the need for the type to be `'number'`?

Comment: see the [reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods) for the data table method `addColumn` -- the first argument can be any of the following --> `'string', 'number', 'boolean', 'date', 'datetime', and 'timeofday'`

Comment: ok, I see thank you

Answer (score 0):

Considering this question was made a year ago and many commented a possible answer maybe you don't need this, but it may help you or someone else.

In order to make the first column type string just change the 'number' to 'string' like this.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  // v change below v
  data.addColumn('string', 'Months since start of COVID 19 (November 2019 = 0 and June 2020 = 8)');
  // ^ change above ^
  data.addColumn('number', 'Recovered');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Death');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Known Cases');
```

And to avoid problems with the data type just add ' ' or " ".

```
  data.addRows([
    ['1',  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
    ['2',  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
    ['3',  25.4,   57, 25.7],
    ['4',  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
    ['5',  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
    ['6',   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
    ['7',   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
    ['8',   7.6, 12.3,  9.6]
  ]);
```

Maybe this links would help anyone who needs help with more information about this.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addColumn